# How to fit a custom probability distribution to histogram

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I know how to fit a normal, or gamma etc. distribution to a histogram, but I want to fit something like

```
f(x) = c * exp(a*x + b*x^2 + c*x^4 + d*x^8)
```

I want to determine the coefficients `a, b, c, d` and create a plot that shows both histogram and my fit.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: As an aside: using the log of the equation and input data may result in an easier (better, faster). I think it's then even a simple linear least squares fit.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I am still searching. Your idea is a good one and it deserves a try.

Comment: It is easy for you to send me a script for this?

Comment: If someone knows a solution and is willing to provide it, they will write an answer below your question.